# Cannot call value of non-function type 'Any?!' :- Firebase,Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code **before** moving to Swift 3:

```
ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            let currentData = snapshot.value!.objectForKey("Dogs")
            if currentData != nil {
            let mylat = (currentData!["latitude"])! as! [String]
            let mylat2 = Double((mylat[0]))
            let mylon = (currentData!["longitude"])! as! [String]
            let mylon2 = Double((mylon[0]))
            let userid = (currentData!["User"])! as! [String]
            let userid2 = userid[0]
            let otherloc = CLLocation(latitude: mylat2!, longitude: mylon2!)
            self.distanceBetweenTwoLocations(self.currentLocation, destination: otherloc, userid: userid2)
            }
        })
```

This is my code **after** moving to Swift 3:

```
ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            let currentData = (snapshot.value! as AnyObject).object("Dogs")
            if currentData != nil {
                let mylat = (currentData!["latitude"])! as! [String]
                let mylat2 = Double((mylat[0]))
                let mylon = (currentData!["longitude"])! as! [String]
                let mylon2 = Double((mylon[0]))
                let userid = (currentData!["User"])! as! [String]
                let userid2 = userid[0]
                let otherloc = CLLocation(latitude: mylat2!, longitude: mylon2!)
                self.distanceBetweenTwoLocations(self.currentLocation, destination: otherloc, userid: userid2)
            }
        })
```

And then I get an error in the 2nd line:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'Any?!'

The only thing I tried is changing the 2nd line to this code:

```
snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
```

But it's not right, there is no "Dogs" included and it's giving me a warning that the `distanceBetweenTwoLocations` code never used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the issue is that when you are instancing and initialising your variable you are telling it that the value its gonna receive will be a **`value`** for the object named `Dogs` present in this snapshot whose type is `AnyObject`.

But **`snapshot.value`** is of type Dictionary i.e `[String:AnyObject]`,`NSDictionary`..

And the `Dogs` node that you retrieve is of type, either Dictionary or an Array.

***Basically you should avoid to store a value in a variable, of type AnyObject***

Try this:-

```
      FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").child("post1").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        if let currentData = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "Dogs") as? [String:AnyObject]{

            let mylat = (currentData["latitude"])! as! [String]
            let mylat2 = Double((mylat[0]))
            let mylon = (currentData["longitude"])! as! [String]
            let mylon2 = Double((mylon[0]))
            let userid = (currentData["User"])! as! [String]
            let userid2 = userid[0]
            let otherloc = CLLocation(latitude: mylat2!, longitude: mylon2!)
            self.distanceBetweenTwoLocations(self.currentLocation, destination: otherloc, userid: userid2)
        }
    })
```

**PS:-** Seeing your JSON structure you might wanna convert it into a Dictionary not a Array

Comment: I'm getting a warning in the if line: `Comparing non-optional value of type '[String : AnyObject]' to nil always returns true`
And also the warning in the `distanceBetweenTwoLocations` which I wrote it in the question.

Comment: I have updated my Answer. as for distanceBetweenTwoLocations i cant speak as i cant see whats written in your code..

Comment: Now it passes through currentData (after I deleted `child("Posts").child("post1")`. But still get a warning in `distanceBetweenTwoLocations` for some reason, I hadn't this problem before moving to Swift 3

Comment: What is `distanceBetweenTwoLocations ` where have you declared it. Cant help you w/o more info..

Comment: Yes it helped me and it is correct! Thank you very much! Apparently the  `distanceBetweenTwoLocations` doesn't work because of Firebase auth connection. I opened new question if you want to help :) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556586/do-not-log-in-to-firebase-after-logging-to-facebook-when-moving-to-swift-3

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 `AnyObject` has been changed to `Any` which really can be anything.
Especially when using key and index subscripting it's now required to tell the compiler the actual type.

The solution is to cast `snapshot.value` to Swift dictionary type `[String:Any]` . The optional binding unwraps the values safely

```
if let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String:Any], 
   let currentData = snapshotValue["Dogs"] as? [String:Any] {

     let mylat = currentData["latitude"] as! [String]
     ...
```

You are using too many exclamation marks. The mark after `latitude"]` is not needed before `as!` and use always `if let` rather than checking for `nil`.

Comment: So far it's good but in the `distanceBetweenTwoLocations` line code code I get a warning: `Result of call to 'distanceBetweenTwoLocations(_:destination:userid:)' is unused`. And as it warned me - for some reason, it's never used (It was used before changing to Swift 3).

Comment: It's nonsensical to call a method to calculate something without using the result.

Comment: You pre-Swift 3 code doesn't use the result either. In Swift 3 you get more warnings about unused results, you could put `@discardableResult` in front of your function or drop the result type if the result is not used at all.

Comment: No way! it worked perfectly! It showed all the users between the location, after changing to swift 3 nothing happens. What is `@discardableResult`?

Comment: Is the optional binding to get `currentData` passed at all? `@discardableResult` suppresses the `unused result` warning.

Comment: No! Just checked and it doesn't passes!

Comment: Ok.. and how do I get the values of the child nodes with this example? Could you explain that to me,please?

Comment: Please ask a question @NazarMedeiros

Comment: Sorry @vadian.. I am banned. I am not able to ask a question =(

Comment: Sorry, too, I'm not that familiar with Firebase @NazarMedeiros

Answer (score 1):

I have also a codepiece which allows you to access to the values of the child node. I hope this helps you:

```
if let snapDict = snapShot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

            for child in snapDict{

                if let name = child.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

                    var _name = name["locationName"]
                    print(_name)
                }

            }

        }
```

Best regards,
Nazar Medeiros